# Know of JavaScript template engines out there?

Tags: javascript, templates, air

I need to generate very big html files based on data entered in a huge form. The project is done in AdobeAIR (js). What templating techniques would you recommend other than Dojo dtl?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [John Resig's micro template](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/).  It's pretty simple and pretty dope.  Now, I don't know how far down that rabbit hole you need to go, but if it's not too far...this works well.

Comment: This uses innerHTML (which might not be proficient for large HTML generation).