# jQuery json/html template rendering plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking at possible approaches to rendering json data received from an Ajax call into HTML tables. I don't want to recreate the table tags and rows each time so a templating seems like the best solution.

Besides 'PURE' plugin/library [(http://beebole.com/pure/)](http://beebole.com/pure/), is there another option that would work for this purpose?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449780/recommended-javascript-html-template-library-for-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554118/know-of-javascript-template-enginges-out-there and (less jQuery specific): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552934/what-javascript-templating-engine-do-you-recommend and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757513/templates-or-similar-for-javascript-programs-in-the-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [jtemplates](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/) for this kind of thing and it works just fine.  Simplistic and lightweight.

Comment: If you have examples, can to share!